# Word count with contraction such as Let's

Tags: countable-nouns, contractions, jokes

In various [situations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE_AFhuHsew) it is desired to count the number of words in a statement. For example, in dictation practice for learning to type.

So in a phrase such as ["Let's go Brandon"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chcwfqhxZz8) how would the contraction be counted? Would this phrase be 2 or 3 words?

Comment: Don't know the rule. Word processors "Bean" and Libreoffice" showing the count as 3.

Comment: What does this guy mean by tagging this thing "satire?" How can a word count be satirical?

Comment: How could 'Let's go Brandon' ever be two words?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see an English Learning question here.  There is no rule that would fit all situations.  It would depend on what you want to measure.  In many (most?) situations the word count is only a rough description of the length of a text. If any real decision depends on whether you count "Let's" as one or two words, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Two words: It's a joke. Heh heh.

Comment: The only real example given is for typing, where real words aren't actually counted.  Instead the word count is the number of characters, including spaces, divided by 5.
So, being able to type 60 words per minute really means typing 300 keystrokes per minute (5 taps per second).

Comment: @RayButterworth The cited example is POTUS giving a word count in a speech. You people. You demand the cites but you never look at them.

Comment: We looked at it.  Are you saying that your entire question was intended as a joke and you don't want a serious answer as to whether "let's" counts as one or two words?

Answer (score 1):

Each system would have to define its own rules. But contractions are "real words," and would probably count. Most automated processes, like word processing software, just count words by counting the strings of letters that are separated by spaces or by certain punctuation like dashes, so even nonsense words would "count."

Note, "Let's go Brandon" would probably be counted as three words; one might argue for four, but it's definitely not two.